# WPF, C# - group by object property

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, grouping

Is there a posibility to group by an object property in wpf?
For exmaple:

```
public class Ausgabe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Mitarbeiter Mitarbeiter { get; set; }
    public Ausgabestatus Status { get; set; }
    public Bestellung Bestellung { get; set; }
}

public class Mitarbeiter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Vorname { get; set; }
    public String Nachname { get; set; }
    public String FullName
    {
        get { return Nachname + " " + Vorname; }
    }
}
```

My datagrid's `ItemsSource` contains a `List<Ausgabe>` which i want to group by `Mitarbeiter.FullName`

```
CollectionView cv = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgErfasst.ItemsSource);
cv.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
PropertyGroupDescription pgd = new PropertyGroupDescription("Mitarbeiter.Vorname");
cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(pgd);
```

This does not seem to work. Is there a way to achieve this kind of grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move FullName to parent class like

```
public class Ausgabe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Mitarbeiter Mitarbeiter { get; set; }
    public Ausgabestatus Status { get; set; }
    public Bestellung Bestellung { get; set; }
    public String FullName
    {
        get { return Mitarbeiter.Nachname + " " + Mitarbeiter.Vorname; }
    }
}
```

and then group

```
PropertyGroupDescription pgd = new PropertyGroupDescription("FullName");
```